# Can't compile trait using gmavenplus plugin

Tags: groovy, traits

I have a trait:

```
trait AbstractSender {

    abstract SentTrigger sendMail(Mail main)

    SentTrigger sentTrigger(Mail mail){
        //do smth here
    }
}
```

And I have a class:

```
class EmailSender implements AbstractSender{

    @Override
    SentTrigger sendMail(Mail mail){
        //do some stuff
    }
}
```

I try to compile it using gmavenplus plugin:

```
<plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.gmavenplus</groupId>
                    <artifactId>gmavenplus-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.5</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>addSources</goal>
                                <goal>addTestSources</goal>
                                <goal>generateStubs</goal>
                                <goal>compile</goal>
                                <goal>testGenerateStubs</goal>
                                <goal>testCompile</goal>
                                <goal>removeStubs</goal>
                                <goal>removeTestStubs</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
<dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                        <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
                        <!-- any version of Groovy \>= 1.5.0 should work here -->
                        <version>2.4.4</version>
                        <scope>runtime</scope>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                </plugin>
```

and get compile exception:

**EmailSender is not abstract and does not override abstract method sentTrigger in AbstractSender**

method **sentTrigger** is implemented. Generated java code looks this way:

```
@groovy.transform.Trait() public interface AbstractSender
 {
;
 SentTrigger sendMail(Mail mail);
 sentTrigger sentTrigger(Mail mail);
}
```

Which does explain compilation error. What do I do wrong with gmavenplus plugin?

Answer (score 0):

It's not a GMavenPlus configuration issue.  You can put this in your GroovyConsole to demonstrate this

```java
trait AbstractSender {
  abstract SentTrigger send(Mail main)

  SentTrigger sentTrigger(Mail mail) { }
}

class EmailSender implements AbstractSender{
  @Override
  SentTrigger sendMail(Mail mail) { }
}

class Mail { }
class SentTrigger { }

new  EmailSender()
```

The error message you're seeing is correct.  `EmailSender` only implements `sendMail()`, not `send()`.  If you rename `sendMail()` to `send()`, it should compile correctly.

Comment: sorry, my fault!  **sendMail** is abstract in trait and is overriden/implemented in concrete class.

Comment: Just to clarify: you are still getting this issue even after renaming the method? Or that was your problem?

Comment: Yes, I still get. I did misprint while preparing problem description. The idea is that trait has abstract and concrete methods. Class implements trait and overrides/implements abstract method. Compiler complains that second concrete method from trait is not implemented.

Comment: Okie dokie.  We're missing something then, because it's working for me. Take a gander at https://github.com/keeganwitt/SO32224258 and once you see what's different either comment or PR so I can reproduce, then we'll update the question.

Comment: One thing I just noticed is that you have the Groovy dependency in the plugin instead of in your project (or maybe in addition to in your project), which probably isn't what you want in the compilation use case.

Comment: Oh, and I tested with Maven 3.3.3.  Shouldn't matter, but just to help us narrow this down.